# TensorFlow Dataset API from_generator End of Sequence Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Here is toy code that duplicates a problem I am encountering when trying to generate/feed training data on the fly using a generator.

```
def makeRand():
    yield np.random.rand(1)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(makeRand, (tf.float32))

iterator = tf.contrib.data.Iterator.from_structure(tf.float32, tf.TensorShape([]))

next_x = iterator.get_next()

init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    a = sess.run(next_x)
    print(a)
    a = sess.run(next_x)
    print(a)
```

The trace looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “test_iterator_gen.py", line 31, in <module>
    a = sess.run(next_x)
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: End of sequence
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator)]]

Caused by op 'IteratorGetNext', defined at:
  File "test_iterator_gen.py", line 23, in <module>
    next_x = iterator.get_next()
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator)]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by incorrect instantiation of a generator.

The error is caused by makeRand() running out of elements to yield.  This is fixed by changing it to:

```
def makeRand():
   while True:
      yield np.random.rand(1)
```